# Gridseed not mining bitcoin - no shares accepted

Tags: cgminer, mac, bfgminer, minerd, gridseed

So I have had my Gridseed (5 chips) for about a week now, and still couldn't mine any Bitcoin, only Scrypt.

I am currently only able to mine with `minerd`, using `Scrypt`, and I am on a Mac.
I tried to mine Bitcoin using `cgminer`, `bfgminer`, `minerd` (versions from MacMiner and others on the internet), tried to compile, nothings seems to work.

**Problem**

- With `cgminer` I can see the hashrate (~`11Gh/s`) but no share is accepted.
- With `bfgminer` it just wont recognize the grid
- With `minerd` it keeps trying and trying, and does nothing.

Looks like `cgminer` is my best shot, but no share is accepted.

I tried on a Windows VM (virtualbox), same outcome!
I have looked all over the internet ([Gridseed-Help](http://www.overclock.net/t/1487157/gridseed-help), [Cryptomining-blog](http://cryptomining-blog.com/1262-download-cgminer-3-7-2-for-windows-scrypt-mining-on-gridseed-5-chip-gc3355-asics/), [GridSeed-Guide on BitcoinTalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=494625.0), and off course [Mac-Mining-Guide](http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/blog/index.php?post/2014/02/27/Mining-with-Gridseed-ASICs-including-DualMiner-on-Mac-OS-X))

Does anyone have any input on here?

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not much of a miner myself, so please take this with a grain of salt.

When I plug in your numbers into a [mining calculator](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/?difficulty=178659257773&hashrate=11000.00&exchangerate=449.85&bitcoinsperblock=25.00&rigcost=30.00&powerconsumption=800.00&powercost=0.10&investmentperiod=355), `11Gh/s` resolve to earnings of just below `0.001 btc` per month. This corresponds e.g. to the minimal "Send threshold" you can set on Slush pool. It's worth is less than $0.5 (for the whole month), where you probably pay a few cents per hour in electricity.

On another help page [Slush pool states](https://slushpool.com/help/#!/manual/monitoring) "Permanently Low or Offline state of your worker can be caused by weak worker whose hash rate is below `10 Gh/s`. We recommend to switch off monitoring for such workers."

I suspect that your hashrate may be so low, that pools don't serve shares at a level where you can succeed, but perhaps you can find out more if you specifically research corresponding to that line of thought.

Comment: Hi @Murch, but even with low speed, do you believe it would not show any accepted/rejected shares? Tks for the reply btw.

Comment: Maybe you could add some log output from `cgminer` to your question, then people that know more about it than I should be able to give a better answer.